# Location Manager's delegate method not getting called

Tags: ios, location

Location manager didUpdateLocations is not getting called.

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

self.locationManager.delegate = self;

[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

for call back I am using this delegate method

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager )manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray )locations
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [locations lastObject]);
}
```

Comment: Have you imported framework for location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import framework CoreLocation

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
    {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

in iOS8 and newer, you have to request permission to use location services explicitly by calling requestAlwaysAuthorization or requestWhenInUseAuthorization.